# Git Web Interface

Tags: php, git, gitweb

I am trying to make the viewgit interface work for my projects.

However I am running into this curious issue with PHP exec:

These 2 unix commands work from inside my viewgit/ directory:

```
/viewgit-> GIT_DIR=/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/repo/.git git rev-list --header --max-count=1 c19e231ad87413798b6a1387a98ec814836fda1e
19e231ad87413798b6a1387a98ec814836fda1e
c19e231ad87413798b6a1387a98ec814836fda1e
tree 4351aa5fb93c3a093902577e5a58138280851152
parent 5099ea6747f8b8a532d153f0536e7be956532a33
author John.smith514-490-6597  1255981013 -0400
committer John.Smith514-490-6597  1255981013 -0400
```

and

```
/viewgit-> GIT_DIR=/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/repo/.git git diff c19e231ad87413798b6a1387a98ec814836fda1e^..c19e231ad87413798b6a1387a98ec814836fda1e
diff --git a/bootstrap.php b/bootstrap.php
index 6cc6336..857890b 100755
--- a/bootstrap.php
+++ b/bootstrap.php
@@ -17,7 +17,7 @@
        );              

        // ZEND LIBRARY
-       //--------------------------------------
+       //---------------------------------------
        // 1.7
        //require_once "Zend/Loader.php";
        //Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
```

however when using php exec only the first one returns an output:

```
$output_1 = array();
$output_2 = array();
$cmd_1 = "GIT_DIR=/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/repo/.git git rev-list --header --max-count=1 c19e231ad87413798b6a1387a98ec814836fda1e";
$cmd_2 = "GIT_DIR=/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/repo/.git git diff c19e231ad87413798b6a1387a98ec814836fda1e^..c19e231ad87413798b6a1387a98ec814836fda1e";
exec($cmd_1, $output_1, $ret);
exec($cmd_2, $output_2, $ret);
```

$output_1 does infact contain the data from the command line ... however, $output_2 is empty !

Any ideas on what is causing this ?

Thx

Comment: seems like it might be a permissions problem somewhere, but can't quite find it

Comment: well I've been making some head way, having logged in as 'daemon' and running the command directly from shell the cmd_2 did not work !
it seems like the ^ to specify the commit identifier is causing the daemon to execute just what comes after, hence in this case: ..c19e231ad87413798b6a1387a98ec814836fda1e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much chagrin I finally landed on a solution....escape the ^.

So I digged into the code and replaced:

```
$text = git_diff($page['project'], "$hash^", $hash);
```

with

```
$text = git_diff($page['project'], "$hash\^", $hash);
```

there might be similar problems elsewhere, still haven't landed on them yet.